# .net core 2.1 EF Core reverse engineering errors VS 2017

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

Not having a great time with doing EF Core Reverse Engineering.

Latest error

> The method or operation is not implemented.

[Scaffold-DbContext "The method or operation is not implemented"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877278/scaffold-dbcontext-the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented)

i get the same errors for both of these commands

**Running this from Package Manager Console within VS 2017:**

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

**and from command prompt:**

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Yes, I do alter them to have both my data source and database.

I get this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.
>   0.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's
>    manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRES
>   ULT: 0x80131040)

I have gotten this before and after i upgraded to the `.net core SDK 2.2.101`

FYI,  my csproj file looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you try updating all your packages to the latest, `2.2.0` for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`. I assume your package for  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is also `2.2.0`. Problem is probably due to version mismatch you are ending up with different versions of same assembly required.

Comment: I did go ahead and install the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource and that did get rid of the error.   I plugged in a random connection string, not valid  -  i will try to do a valid one and then if that doesn't work - I will try your solution @penleychan  thx

Comment: I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877278/scaffold-dbcontext-the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented

Comment: Try "EF Core Power Tools"

Comment: I did that @ErikEJ  and then also the latest core 2.2.x.x  SDK install

Answer (score 0):

Between installing the EF power Tools and the Latest Core 2.2.x.x SDK I am now able to change my project to use dropdown change to the .net core 2.2 (it was previously only able to do 2.1.

Then with Nuget updates etc.. , it finally works!