# Scaffold-DbContext "The method or operation is not implemented"

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

Not having a great time.

PM>  command run

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver;Database=mysqlserverdb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables Settings -verbose
```

Error:

> The method or operation is not implemented.

`System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.ProviderCodeGenerator.GenerateUseProvider(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.GenerateOnConfiguring(String connectionString, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.GenerateClass(IModel model, String contextName, String connectionString, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.WriteCode(IModel model, String namespace, String contextName, String connectionString, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, String namespace, String contextDir, String contextName, String connectionString, ModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)`

Comment: Solved the Diagnostics issue, but my old question shows my CSPROJ file    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875493/net-core-2-1-ef-core-reverse-engineering-errors-vs-2017

Comment: Not sure if you have solved it yet, realized you are using mysql, and I came across this before, and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616506/error-the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented-while-scaffolding-mysql-datab) resolved my issue.

Comment: Not using mysql

Comment: oh,  sorry -  "mysqlserverdb"   made it sort of look like mysql ,  but "my sql server " rather ...  as a replacement for the real name.    thx though  - i did already see that SO question/answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between installing the **EF power Tools** and the **Latest Core 2.2.x.x SDK** I am now able to change my project to use dropdown change to the .net core 2.2  (it was previously only able to do 2.1.

Then with Nuget updates etc.. , it finally works!