# Sql Server using Scaffold-DbContext, get error: The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

From my project:

netcoreapp2.2

all
      runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers

I was using Scaffold-DbContext for months，and today did nothing change with my project, but get error like 'The EF Core tools version is older ...'. I found someone suggest to update `Microsoft.NETCore.App` to 2.2.x, I did so, then get new error:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.ProviderCodeGenerator.GenerateUseProvider(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.GenerateOnConfiguring(String connectionString, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.GenerateClass(IModel model, String contextName, String connectionString, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.WriteCode(IModel model, String namespace, String contextName, String connectionString, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, String namespace, String contextDir, String contextName, String connectionString, ModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

The method or operation is not implemented.

I found a question [Scaffold-DbContext "The method or operation is not implemented"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877278/scaffold-dbcontext-the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented?noredirect=1&lq=1), seems like what I ask, but he did not explain clear how resolve the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to modify the question, the content mess. my project:   <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: post what is listed if you execute `dotnet --list-sdks` and `dotnet --list-runtimes` commands

Comment: 1.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
1.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Comment: it is better to edit your question to add additional information. Post pls your `csproj` file and what gives `dotnet --version` command if you run it from a project folder.

Comment: yes, I know. I want to post csproj in my quetion at beginning, but it's confusion, and i can't edit my question now. my dotnet version is 2.2.103.

Comment: everything looks OK. May be it worth to install the latest version of SDK